# Elasticsearch is not working with Alphanumeric

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am having alphanumeric codes like `AA111, 111AA, AA-111, AAAA, 1111`. Below is the mapping for elastic search

```
"name" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "analyzer" : "standard",
      "fields" : {
        "lower_case_sort" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "normalizer" : "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "copy_to" : "default"
    }
```

The default mapping is like below

```
"default" : {
  "type" : "text",
  "analyzer" : "index_ngram",
  "search_analyzer" : "search_ngram"
},
```

When we search with `AAA` or `AA`, It returns results. But when we search by `111` it does not return any result.

Below is the query

```
"bool" : {
            "filter" : [
              {
                "match" : {
                  "default" : {
                    "query" : "111",
                    "operator" : "AND",
                    "prefix_length" : 0,
                    "max_expansions" : 50,
                    "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
                    "lenient" : false,
                    "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
                    "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
                    "boost" : 1.0
                  }
                }
              },
```

Comment: will share the working example on your data

Comment: Could you please share mapping for `default` as you are searching on default field and not on `name` field.

Answer (score 0):

Its happening as you are using the some analyzer on your `default` field, which is removing the numbers from your text (simple analyzer is one of them), you need to use a tokeniser which doesn't remove them like [edge-ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html#analysis-edgengram-tokenizer) and search on them, or use the `standard` analyzer which also works with the numbers.

Comment: are you sure standard analyzer will remove number from text ? because when i tried using `_analyze` api it is not removing and it is generating `aa111` for `AA111` and `aa` and `111` for `AA-111` text.

Comment: @SagarPatel yes, my bad it seems OP is using some other analyzer which is removing the numbers, its simple analyzer which does that, updated my answer

Comment: @SagarPatel Added default mapping

Comment: @LalitChattar can you add the definition of `search_ngram` as default analyzer is using it as a search time analyzer which is being used in your match query

Comment: @LalitChattar can you provide the requested info?

Comment: @LalitChattar Any update here?

Comment: @LalitChattar its been long time, please provoide update here